# Rendered more hooks than previous render error in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

This is the index file which is a container for taskCards.

```js
import TaskCard from './TaskCard'

export function Task() {
    const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.tasks);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const [task,setTask] = useState("");
    const [time,setTime] = useState("");


    function submitTask() {
        let newTask = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
            content: task,
            time: time,
            remainingTime: time,
            isRunning: false,
        };
        dispatch(create(newTask));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="number" onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="button" value="submit task" onClick={submitTask} />
            {tasks.map((i) => TaskCard(i))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is TaskCard.js file.

```js
import useTimer from '../../hooks/useTimer' // custom hook which decreases `time` per second using setInterval API 

export default function TaskCard(task) {
    const delay = 1000;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useTimer(
        () => {
            if (task.remainingTime > 0) {
                dispatch(tick(task.id));
            }else if (task.remainingTime === 0) {
                dispatch(toggleIsRunning(task.id))
            }
        },
        task.isRunning ? delay : null
    );

    return (
        <div key={task.id} style={{ padding: "10px", width: "200px", margin: "20px auto", border: "orange solid 1px", borderRadius: "5px" }}>
            <p>{task.content}</p>
            <p>{task.remainingTime}</p>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(remove(task.id))}>remove</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(toggleIsRunning(task.id))}>play/pause</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(reset(task.id))}>reset</button>
        </div>
    );
    
}
```

The code renders fine initially. but upon adding a new task, i get this error

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Task. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useReducer                 useReducer
3. useMemo                    useMemo
4. useRef                     useRef
5. useRef                     useRef
6. useRef                     useRef
7. useRef                     useRef
8. useLayoutEffect            useLayoutEffect
9. useLayoutEffect            useLayoutEffect
10. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
11. useContext                useContext
12. useState                  useState
13. useState                  useState
14. undefined                 useContext
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at Task (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:492:80)
    at div
    at App
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:36550:20)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2430
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:67
error @ react-dom.development.js:43

react-dom.development.js:15162 Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
    at updateWorkInProgressHook (react-dom.development.js:15162)
    at updateRef (react-dom.development.js:15694)
    at Object.useRef (react-dom.development.js:16433)
    at useRef (react.development.js:1516)
    at useTimer (useTimer.js:4)
    at TaskCard (TaskCard.js:9)
    at index.js:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Task (index.js:29)
```

How can i fix this issue ? should i restructure my code ? Do let me know if i need to add some more details to improve clarity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems an extra `useContext` hook was used... please include the code where the hooks are used. Looks like a provider in `App` component.

Comment: `{tasks.map((i) => TaskCard(i))}` should be `{tasks.map((i) => <TaskCard {...i} />)}`

Comment: Ah, good catch @PatrickRoberts in this case then `Task` should probably change `task` to `props` so it's overtly clear it's the `props` object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{tasks.map((i) => TaskCard(i))}
```

Because you're calling the function `TaskCard` directly within `Task`, the `useDispatch()` hook in `TaskCard` is actually being treated as a hook call within `Task` instead. You have to specify that `TaskCard` is component instead of a normal function in order for React to correctly treat the `useDispatch()` as a hook call within the function component `TaskCard`:

```
{tasks.map((props) => <TaskCard {...props} />)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be handled by using a React component rather than a function. Rather than passing data as params, you would pass them as props.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).